# Website: Facebook, NodeJS+ Express: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domain”

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, express, web

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I have been trying to address this issue for two weeks but have been unable to solve the problem.

I am trying to utilize Facebook login on my website, but it keeps stating "Cannot load URL", telling me that I did not add in the domains/subdomains.

I made my website `https` instead of HTTP to cater to Facebook's new terms but that hasn't fixed the issue.

Please, help me with this if you are knowledgeable on this subject.

Comment: This is what the error showed. https://imgur.com/a/rga4UBV

Comment: Facebook login does not work with IP addresses, you need to use an actual host name.

Comment: @CBroe Does that mean I can't use localhost though?

Comment: localhost should work, at least that used to in the past, and was exempt from the HTTPS requirement as well. If not, using a service like https://ngrok.com can also be an option.

Comment: Hm, is there anyway to use facebook login with https:// and localhost? I want to avoid using any other applications as much as possible. Hopefully someone can fix this error :(

Comment: If you can generate yourself a certificate for localhost, and get your browser to accept that, then that should be no problem. Not sure that is actually necessary here though; did you change your Valid OAuth Redirect URIs accordingly yet? In your screenshot, you only had 127.0.0.1 URLs in there.

Comment: I'm trying to redirect it to the same page, haven't created the other pages yet. But it didn't work. Changed from HTTP to https and vice versa but still not working. Apologies for the late reply as computer had to undergo repair.